# LazyInitializationException on eagerly fetched (detached) collection

Tags: ajax, hibernate, jpa, primefaces, lazy-initialization

First some info:

- I'm using:

  - Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE
  - Hibernate 4.1.5.SP1
  - JSF 2.0?
  - OpenSessionInViewFilter (org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter)
  - PrimeFaces 3.3.1
  - Lombok 0.11.2
  - JBoss 7.1.1.Final

**The short version:**

When my entity `Emloyee` becomes detached (and thus it's eagerly fetched collection of `Location`s too), I cannot call `Employee.getLocations().add()` without getting a `LazyInitializationException`. Using a non-JPA based collection to act as a transfer object works.

**The Long version:**

I have an entity `Employee` that has a collection of `Location`s:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, of = {})
@ToString(callSuper = true, of = {})
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Employee extends Person
{
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "location_employee",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "location_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Location>   locations   = new HashSet<Location>();
}
```

`Employee` extends from `Person` which has some strings like name, etc. but these are not relevant.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = { "id", "name" })
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long    id;

    private String  name;
}
```

The `Location` class too is very simple:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = { "id", "name" })
@Entity
public class Location
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long            id;

    private String          name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "location_employee",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "location_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Employee>   employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
}
```

All collections are lazy by default. However in my JSF page I want to add `Location`s to an existing `Employee`. To do this I eager load my `Employee` using the following backing bean:

```
@Named
@Scope("view")
public class BackingBean
{
    @Inject
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
    private Employee        employeeFull;
    @Inject
    private LocationDAO locationDAO;
    private List<Location> locations;

    public Employee getSelectedEmployeeFull()
    {
        if (selectedEmployeeFull == null)
        {
            selectedEmployeeFull = employeeDAO.getEagerById(1L);
        }
        return selectedEmployeeFull;
    }

    public void setEmployeeFull(Employee e)
    {
        employeeFull = e;
    }

    public List<Location> getLocations()
    {
        if (locations == null)
        {
            locations = locationDAO.getAll()
        }
        return locations;
    }

    //...
}
```

The `EmployeeDAO` class including the eager load query:

```
@Named
public class EmployeeDAO
{
    @Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Employee getEager(Long id)
    {
        Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select e from Employee e join fetch e.locations where e.id = :id");
        q.setParameter("id", id);
        try
        {
            return (Employee) q.uniqueResult();
        }
        catch (NonUniqueObjectException ex)
        {
            //Exception logging/handling
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In my JSF I have the following snippet:

```
<p:dialog dynamic="true">
    <h:form>
        <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Locations" value="#{employeeBean.employeeFull.locations}">
            <f:selectItems var="location" itemLabel="#{location.name}" value="#{employeeBean.locations}" />
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>

        <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{employeeBean.update}"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

When I open the dialog it loads the `employeeFull` property fine, and fills the `selectCheckboxMenu` with `Location`s and marks the `Location`s the `Employee` already has.

However when I click the save button (without changing anything) and the form gets submitted the `Employee.locations` collection trows a `LazyInitializationException`:

```
09:36:42,633 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:394) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:386) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:379) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:382) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:315) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.selectcheckboxmenu.SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.java:34) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.component.dialog.Dialog.processValidators(Dialog.java:359) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.3.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155) [spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:119) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
```

The `EmployeeBean.update` method is never called as the breakpoint set on it is never hit.

<strike>Now for the grand finale: How can I prevent this `LazyInitializationException`.</strike>

**EDIT**

I have created a workaround, but this is probably not the best solution:

In the JSF page:

```
<p:dialog dynamic="true" onShow="loadSelectedEmployee()">
    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand action="#{employeeBean.loadSelectedEmployee}" name="loadSelectedEmployee" update=":editEmployeeDialogContent" />
    </h:form>
    <p:outputPanel layout="block" id="editEmployeeDialogContent">
        <h:form rendered="#{employeeBean.selectedEmployeeLoaded}">
            <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Locations" value="#{employeeBean.selectedEmployee.locations}">
                <f:selectItems var="location" itemLabel="#{location.name}" value="#{employeeBean.locations}" />
            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>

            <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{employeeBean.update}"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

In the backing bean:

```
public void loadSelectedEmployee()
{
    if (!selectedEmployeeLoaded)
    {
        selectedEmployee.setLocations(locationManager
                .getByEmployee(selectedEmployee));
        selectedEmployee.setRoles(roleManager
                .getByEmployee(selectedEmployee));
        selectedEmployeeLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try tracking down the problem by removing unnecessary things like converter etc..

Comment: @JMelnik I removed the converter, the stacktrace differs only from line 4 to line 12. The problem rises when JSF is calling the `PersistentBag.add()` method while the bag is disconnected.

Comment: Try checking with hibernate if collection is initialized, put it somewhere in your code (look stacktrace). how to check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4306498/685962

Comment: @JMelnik When the eager query is executed I see the locations collection being fetched with a join. Then when I call `Hibernate.isInitialized()` on the collection, it returns true. No additional query is fired. Using a non-JPA collection works by the way (I'm updating my question within seconds).

Comment: It may be unnecessary, but try also changing Set to Collection = ArrayList

Comment: Also look here, this might be the issue: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1523

Answer (score 1):

This is definitly a bug and I guess either in Primefaces or in Jboss-jsf-api-2.1.
I can modify the PersistenSet directly in the controller, so its definitly eager loaded, but when bound to the JSF component (I am using Primefaces selectCheckboxMenu) it's also throwing that LazyInitalizationException.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a HQL over an entity that has no relationship to marked "eager" will continue the brand of "lazy" and attempt to query the data at the time of "get".

For this case an example of forcing initialize the relationship would be:

```
Hibernate.initialize(e.getLocations());
```

Integrated:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Employee getEager(Long id)
{
    Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select e from Employee e join fetch e.locations where e.id = :id");
    q.setParameter("id", id);
    try
    {
        final Employee e = (Employee) q.uniqueResult();
        if(e != null){
            Hibernate.initialize(e.getLocations());
        }
        return e;

    }
    catch (NonUniqueObjectException ex)
    {
        //Exception logging/handling
        return null;
    }
}
```

Regads,