# Sessions with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, session, jpa

When I load a lazy loaded list in a rich:dataTable I always get the "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" error.

This is of course because the session is closed at this state.

My Question how can I use sessions by just using JPA (no spring etc.). Do i really need the HibernateUtil stuff or Hibernate.Initialize(..). I would rather not use this Hibernate specific things, just plain JPA. And no EAGER fetch.

My current code:

Entity:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")})
public class User implements Serializable {

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<UserTournament> userTournament = new ArrayList<UserTournament>();

...

}
```

DAO:

```
@Stateless(name = "usercontroller")
public class UserController implements UserControllerInterface {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

...

  @Override
  public List<UserTournament> getUserTournaments(Integer userid) {
    User user = loadUser(userid);
    return user.getUserTournament();
  }

...

}
```

Named Bean:

```
@Named("myTournBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyTournamentsBean implements Serializable {

  @EJB
  private UserControllerInterface userController;

  private List<UserTournament> tournaments;

...

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
...
    tournaments = userController.getUserTournaments(userid);
  }
...
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="titleCell">

    <rich:dataScroller for="table" maxPages="5" />
        <rich:dataTable value="#{myTournBean.tournaments}" var="tourn"
                            id="table" rows="10">
            <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Id" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{tourn.id}" />
            </rich:column>
        </rich:dataTable>
    <rich:dataScroller for="table" maxPages="5" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

EDIT:

The [link](http://ocpsoft.org/java/spring-to-java-ee-a-migration-guide-cdi-jsf-jpa-jta-ejb/) form @BoristheSpider was very helpful. I'm not completely through it but this already solved my issue:

```
@Stateful
@ConversationScoped
public class Service
{
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to keep the session open you will have to load the data. If you don't want to eager fetch you are out of luck...

Comment: Here we go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770450/standard-jpa-method-to-initialize-lazy-entity

Comment: but is there no way to keep the session open with JPA? I am quite new to this JPA topic. So far I used the HibernateUtil approach once. But I would rather avoid it and just use JPA with the persictence.xml and no additional hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: Keeping the session open is orthogonal to JPA. You could easily implement the open-session-in-view pattern using start JavaEE filters in the web application.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I saw that pattern with the HibernateUtil: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView but how is it done with JPA? Do you have a link?

Comment: [Here](http://ocpsoft.org/java/spring-to-java-ee-a-migration-guide-cdi-jsf-jpa-jta-ejb/) is a very thorough tutorial on using JavaEE to do Spring stuff - like open session in view.

Comment: Extended persistence context inside a stateful bean should work without any special tricks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want you class to be dependant on Hibernate, then create a utility class and depend on this utility class to initialize your associations:

```
public class JPAUtils {
    public static void initialize(...) {
        Hibernate.initialize(...);
    }
}
```

And when you change your JPA provider (which has almost 0 chance to happen), then rewrite this method using the corresponding helper class of your new JPA provider, or by simply calling a method of the object or collection to initialize.