# JPA equivalent command to Hibernate.initialize

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, jpa-2.1

I have a Lazy collection that I want to initialize at will in my service/controller. At this moment I can do:

```
Hibernate.initialize( myEntity.getListOfThings() );
```

This command is hibernate dependent and does not make the implementation of JPA transparent. Is there a JPA elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no JPA equivalent. You can learn [if the object is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306463/how-to-test-whether-lazy-loaded-jpa-collection-is-initialized) and than use one of the two options, either accessing the properties while the object is still attached to persistence context, what I typically see is calling size, just for the sake of initializing the collection

```
myEntity.getListOfThings().size();
```

or use a query for initialization.

Comment: Wouldn't hibernate return a proxy instead of the real object? When I try to access the object I think it is still attached to the persistence context but results a LazyInitializationException.

You had my upvote but it would be helpfull if you could elaborate a bit the alternative

Comment: but I meant calling a property against a proxy object, if still attached that will fully initialize it. I've updated the answer to reflect it better

Comment: Why would I get `LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.app.App.User.listOfThings, could not initialize proxy - no Session` ? I'm using Spring Data and I annotate my controller method with `@Transactional`