# Is Persistence.getPersistenceUtil a simpler way of testing whether a lazy loaded JPA collection is initialized when using Spring Boot repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

This question is given an answer here - [How to test whether lazy loaded JPA collection is initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306463/how-to-test-whether-lazy-loaded-jpa-collection-is-initialized)

The answer given there makes use of `PersistenceUnitUtil`. However, in order to get a PersistenceUnitUtil you need to access the EntityManagerFactory. Spring framework uses repositories to hide all that EntityManager stuff, which makes that solution awkward (but not impossible).

However there is a standard JPA way of accessing a similar object `PersistenceUtil` - just as `Persistence.getPersistenceUtil` - which provides an object with the same methods used in the above answer.

In the Spring framework, using repositories, this appears to be a much simpler way to access those helpful `isLoaded` methods.

Is there is any reason not to use that simpler approach?

Comment: The following link https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-lazy-collections will clarify you when you will receive a `LazyInitializationException` and how to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks - but I am aware of that. As in the referred answer above, I want to be able to use the isLoaded methods.

Comment: As I can see each of these ways has its own implementation of `PersistenceUnitUtil` but both of them end up using `PersistenceUtilHelper` from hibernate to determine the state of the object.
 `Persistence.getPersistenceUtil` is just more generic as if you can change JPA implementation underneath without changing your code.